# Rails - passing data hash from Ruby to JS via js.erb file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, interpolation

This my controller:

```
      def show
        @result = {"data"=>{"8"=>{"typeA"=>{"tier"=>[1,2],"message"=>"message"},"typeB"=>"sto"}}}
        respond_to do |format|
          format.js
        end
      end
```

So in `show.js.erb` I want to be able to create a JS object `data` that is `@result['data']`. But it's really not working... The closest I can seem to get is a string representation, but then `JSON.parse` fails to convert it to a JS object because all the characters have been encoded:

```
  console.log("<%= @result['data'] %>")
  var data = JSON.parse("<%= @result['data'] %>") 
  console.log(data)

ACTUAL OUTPUT

  > {&quot;8&quot;:{&quot;typeA&quot;:{&quot;message&quot;:&quot;message&quot;,&quot;tier&quot;:[1,2]},&quot;typeB&quot;:&quot;sto&quot;}}

  > Uncaught SYntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1

DESIRED OUTPUT (for second console.log)

  > {"8":{"typeA":{"tier":[1,2],"message":"message"},"typeB":"sto"}}
```

Note I tried to do `@result.to_json`, this didn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you use the [`raw` view helper](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper/raw), Rails will automatically escape tags.

This should do the trick:

```
  var data = <%= raw(@result.to_json) %>;
  console.log(data);
  console.log(typeof data);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
@result.to_json
```

or `j` or `escape_javascript` helpers?

```
var data = JSON.parse("<%= j @result['data'] %>")
```

Comment: yes, unfortunately I get the same output with `j`